# Keep adding rows to a table during ForEach C#

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, datatables

I have the below code which works great in running a foreach statement to run through multiple files, populating data tables called dt_LearnDelivery and dt_LearnDelFAM. However, for each file that it runs through, it's overwriting the existing content of the table. What I want to happen is every time it reads a new file through the foreach statements, it's adding to any existing rows in dt_LearnDelivery and dt_LearnDelFAM. Any suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MessageLogging;

namespace ILRValidation
{
    public static partial class Validation
    {
    static MessageLogging.Msgs msgs = Msgs.Instance;
    static MessageLogging.Progress progress = Progress.Instance;
    /// <summary>
    /// Takes ILR Converted dataset, and checks for null values and outputs to separate validation dataset
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ds_NullChecks">ILR XML Import Dataset</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DataSet NullChecks(DataSet ds_NullChecks)
    {
        return Checks(ds_NullChecks);
    } 

    public static DataSet NullChecks(string xmlPath)
    {

        DataSet ds_xmlDataset = new DataSet();
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(xmlPath);

        ds_xmlDataset.ReadXml(fileInfo.FullName, XmlReadMode.Auto);

        return Checks(ds_xmlDataset);
    }
    private static DataSet Checks(DataSet dataset)
    {
        msgs.AddMsg("Entering Checks");
        progress.ResetValue();

        if (ds_Validation.Tables.Contains("LearningDelivery_NullValues"))
        {
            ds_Validation.Tables.Remove("LearningDelivery_NullValues");
        }

        if (ds_Validation.Tables.Contains("LearnerDeliveryFAM_NullValues"))
        {
            ds_Validation.Tables.Remove("LearnerDeliveryFAM_NullValues");
        }

        msgs.AddMsg("Adding Extra columns to LearningDelivery & LearningDeliveryFAM");
        dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Columns.Add("LearnRefNumber").SetOrdinal(0);
        dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Columns.Add("Comments");
        dataset.Tables["LearningDeliveryFAM"].Columns.Add("LearnRefNumber").SetOrdinal(0);
        dataset.Tables["LearningDeliveryFAM"].Columns.Add("Comments");

        DataTable dt_LearnDelivery = new DataTable();
        dt_LearnDelivery.TableName = "LearningDelivery_NullValues";



        foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Columns)
        {
            dt_LearnDelivery.Columns.Add(dataColumn.ColumnName);
        }



        //Make a table to hold the issues with LearnerDeliveryFAM
        DataTable dt_LearnDelFAM = new DataTable();
        dt_LearnDelFAM.TableName = "LearnerDeliveryFAM_NullValues";

        foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dataset.Tables["LearningDeliveryFAM"].Columns)
        {
            dt_LearnDelFAM.Columns.Add(dataColumn.ColumnName);
        }

        progress.SetMax(dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Select("Isnull(LearnAimRef,'') = ''").Count());
        progress.SetMessage("Checked for issues 1 of 9");

        //Add "No Aim" issues to new table
        foreach (DataRow dr in dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Select("Isnull(LearnAimRef,'') = ''"))
        {
            dr["LearnRefNumber"] = dr.GetParentRow("Learner_LearningDelivery")["LearnRefNumber"].ToString();
            dr["Comments"] = "LearnAimRef - No Aim Ref Supplied";

            dt_LearnDelivery.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);

            progress.IncProgress();
        }

        progress.int_Progress = 0;
        progress.SetMax(dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Select("Isnull(AimType,'') = ''").Count());
        progress.SetMessage("Checked for issues 2 of 9");

        //Add "No Aim Type" issues to new table
        foreach (DataRow dr in dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Select("Isnull(AimType,'') = ''"))
        {

            dr["LearnRefNumber"] = dr.GetParentRow("Learner_LearningDelivery")["LearnRefNumber"].ToString();
            dr["Comments"] = "AimType - No Aim Type Supplied";

            dt_LearnDelivery.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);

            progress.IncProgress();
        }

        progress.int_Progress = 0;
        progress.SetMax(dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Select("Isnull(AimSeqNumber,'') = ''").Count());
        progress.SetMessage("Checked for issues 3 of 9");

        //Add "No Aim Sequence Number" issues to new table
        foreach (DataRow dr in dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Select("Isnull(AimSeqNumber,'') = ''"))
        {

            dr["LearnRefNumber"] = dr.GetParentRow("Learner_LearningDelivery")["LearnRefNumber"].ToString();
            dr["Comments"] = "AimSeqNumber - No Aim Sequence Number Supplied";

            dt_LearnDelivery.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);

            progress.IncProgress();
        }
        progress.int_Progress = 0;
        progress.SetMax(dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Select("Isnull(LearnStartDate,'') = ''").Count());
        progress.SetMessage("Checked for issues 4 of 9");

        //Add "No Learner Start Date" issues to new table
        foreach (DataRow dr in dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Select("Isnull(LearnStartDate,'') = ''"))
        {

            dr["LearnRefNumber"] = dr.GetParentRow("Learner_LearningDelivery")["LearnRefNumber"].ToString();
            dr["Comments"] = "LearnStartDate - No Learner Start Date Supplied";

            dt_LearnDelivery.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);

            progress.IncProgress();
        }

        progress.int_Progress = 0;
        progress.SetMax(dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Select("Isnull(LearnPlanEndDate,'') = ''").Count());
        progress.SetMessage("Checked for issues 5 of 9");

        //Add "No Learner Planned End Date" issues to new table
        foreach (DataRow dr in dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Select("Isnull(LearnPlanEndDate,'') = ''"))
        {

            dr["LearnRefNumber"] = dr.GetParentRow("Learner_LearningDelivery")["LearnRefNumber"].ToString();
            dr["Comments"] = "LearnPlanEndDate - No Learner Planned End Date Supplied";

            dt_LearnDelivery.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);

            progress.IncProgress();
        }

        progress.int_Progress = 0;
        progress.SetMax(dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Select("Isnull(FundModel,'') = ''").Count());
        progress.SetMessage("Checked for issues 6 of 9");

        //Add "No Funding Model" issues to new table
        foreach (DataRow dr in dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Select("Isnull(FundModel,'') = ''"))
        {

            dr["LearnRefNumber"] = dr.GetParentRow("Learner_LearningDelivery")["LearnRefNumber"].ToString();
            dr["Comments"] = "FundModel - No Funding Model Supplied";

            dt_LearnDelivery.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);

            progress.IncProgress();
        }

        progress.int_Progress = 0;
        progress.SetMax(dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Select("Isnull(DelLocPostCode,'') = ''").Count());
        progress.SetMessage("Checked for issues 7 of 9");

        //Add "No Delivery Location Postcode" issues to new table
        foreach (DataRow dr in dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Select("Isnull(DelLocPostCode,'') = ''"))
        {

            dr["LearnRefNumber"] = dr.GetParentRow("Learner_LearningDelivery")["LearnRefNumber"].ToString();
            dr["Comments"] = "DelLocPostCode - No Delivery Location Postcode Supplied";

            dt_LearnDelivery.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);

            progress.IncProgress();
        }

        progress.int_Progress = 0;
        progress.SetMax(dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Select("Isnull(CompStatus,'') = ''").Count());
        progress.SetMessage("Checked for issues 8 of 9");

        //Add "No Completion Status" issues to new table
        foreach (DataRow dr in dataset.Tables["LearningDelivery"].Select("Isnull(CompStatus,'') = ''"))
        {

            dr["LearnRefNumber"] = dr.GetParentRow("Learner_LearningDelivery")["LearnRefNumber"].ToString();
            dr["Comments"] = "CompStatus - No Completion Status Supplied";

            dt_LearnDelivery.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);

            progress.IncProgress();
        }

        progress.int_Progress = 0;
        progress.SetMax(dataset.Tables["LearningDeliveryFAM"].Select("Isnull(LearnDelFAMCode,'') = '' and LearnDelFAMType = 'SOF'").Count());
        progress.SetMessage("Checked for issues 9 of 9");

        //Add "No SOF" issues to new table
        foreach (DataRow dr in dataset.Tables["LearningDeliveryFAM"].Select("Isnull(LearnDelFAMCode,'') = '' and LearnDelFAMType = 'SOF'"))
        {
            DataRow AimRow = dr.GetParentRow("LearningDelivery_LearningDeliveryFAM");

            dr["LearnRefNumber"] = AimRow.GetParentRow("Learner_LearningDelivery")["LearnRefNumber"].ToString();
            dr["Comments"] = "LearnDelFAMCode is null where LearnDelFAMType is SOF";

            dt_LearnDelFAM.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);

            progress.IncProgress();
        }


        ds_Validation.Tables.Add(dt_LearnDelivery);
        ds_Validation.Tables.Add(dt_LearnDelFAM);

        return ds_Validation;
    }
}
}
```

After it runs through a file, adding to a data table, it then goes to another class and does:

```
    using InfExcelExtension;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ILRValidation;


namespace ILRChecks
{
    internal static partial class ILRReport
    {
        internal static void NullChecks()
        {
            Global.Progress.ResetValue();            

            foreach (string str_FileLocation in Global.fileNames)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(str_FileLocation);




                DataSet ds_NullValue = ILRValidation.Validation.NullChecks(str_FileLocation);

                ds_NullValue.ToWorkBook(Global.output);



            }
            Global.Progress.SetMax(Global.fileNames.Count());
            Global.Progress.IncProgress();
            Global.Progress.ResetValue();




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new rows to a DataTable programmatically C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559435/add-new-rows-to-a-datatable-programmatically-c-sharp)

Comment: One thing I'd *highly* recommend is to break up that `Checks` method. It's doing *a lot* for a single method and isn't going to do you any favors while debugging.

Answer (score 2):

In every run of the method `Checks(DataSet dataset)` you recreate the table object with

```
DataTable dt_LearnDelivery = new DataTable();
```

This variable needs to be promoted to a static variable for the class

```
namespace ILRValidation
{
    public static partial class Validation
    {
        static MessageLogging.Msgs msgs = Msgs.Instance;
        static MessageLogging.Progress progress = Progress.Instance;

        static DataTable dt_LearnDelivery = new DataTable();
        ...
```

And yes, do yourself a favor and break up the method into smaller ones as suggested by @Broots Waymb.

Comment: This is just the tip of the iceberg here. How do you plan to initialize that table? And why everything static? This introduces a requirement to clean everything if you want to reuse the Validation class for a new set of files.